# Magento PDO MYSQL

Tags: php, magento

Estou com esse problema sendo que o PDO já encontra-se ativo no php.ini do servidor.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse "tópico" do nosso [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/18246)

Comment: PDO instalado não significa que a PDO_MYSQL tbm está instalado. Use `phpinfo();` para se certificar de que as extensões desejadas estão instaladas.